# Obtain index of object that contains a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to obtain the first index that an object belongs to in an array. For example:

```
winning = [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
   1: 0
   2: 0
   3: 0

1: Object
   4: 0
   5: 0
   6: 0

2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
```

What I need to do is run a command like this:

```
winning[objNum][square] = -1;
```

`square` represents a `div` id that was clicked. What I need to happen is when I click a div I need it to search through the `winning` object array and find out what object contains the number of the div that was clicked and store in in the variable `objNum. Is there a jQuery or javascript method for doing this?

Example if I click on a div that has an `id` of 5 the command that needs to run is:

```
winning[1][5] = -1;
```

This is how I am creating the object

```
var winning = [{1:0, 2:0, 3:0},{4:0, 5:0, 6:0},{7:0, 8:0, 9:0},
               {1:0, 4:0, 7:0},{2:0, 5:0, 8:0},{3:0, 6:0, 9:0},
               {1:0, 5:0, 9:0},{7:0, 5:0, 3:0}];
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="blah">
                <div id="1" class="boardSquares"></div>
                <div id="2" class="boardSquares"></div>
                <div id="3" class="boardSquares"></div>
                <div id="4" class="boardSquares"></div>
                <div id="5" class="boardSquares"></div>
                <div id="6" class="boardSquares"></div>
                <div id="7" class="boardSquares"></div>
                <div id="8" class="boardSquares"></div>
                <div id="9" class="boardSquares"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: need to see map of objects to do that

Comment: @charlietfl I added some code I believe it is what you wanted

Comment: if ID's aren't unique have a problem. WIll need way to match array index. Please create demo with html. I'm guessing you can get index based on html structure

Comment: the ID's are unique to the div

Comment: Sounds like `Math.floor(square/3) == objNum` is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since tagged jQuery:

```
$.each(winning, function(idx, obj){
    if( obj[ square] != undefined ){
        obj[ square]= -1;
         return false;/* break loop*/
    }
});
```

All keys in all objects must be unique.

If could see your html structure, would likely be able to use it to index the object within array and not have to perform this loop

Comment: I added more code and tried yours but it does not update anything

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net with code you are trying. I could but I don't see relation between your divs and the 3 keys in each object. I believe your data can be restructured but still not clear what it's all for yet

Comment: object[square] might exist and be zero. You should use "square in obj" instead. http://jsfiddle.net/upN8d/

Comment: if html structure is that simple....you can use index of element in DOM...and skip loop like this

Answer (score 0):

It was pretty simple...:D...just some different way to think. check out the demo...

**http://jsfiddle.net/sjLQ3/**

```
var objs=[{0:0,1:0},{2:0,3:0},{4:0,5:0}],n;

$('.click').click(function(){
    n=$(this).index();
    objs.forEach(function(v,i){  //not a jquery function
        if(objs[i][n]!=undefined)  objs[i][n]-=1;
    });

});
```